# Could not update to iOS 11 because ‘an error occurred installing’

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

Been trying this for more than 10 times already. Both from iTunes from my laptop and my phone. What should I do? Been doing the usual restart but still that still shows up.

[image]

iPhone 5s

Answer (score 1):

This happened when there is not enough space.

Before trying to reinstall you need to delete the old update.

To do this go to Settings -> General -> Storage & iCloud Storage -> Manage Storage.

Then look for the update and delete it:

[image]

Then try to install the update using iTunes:

Open iTunes and select your device 
from the left panel

Click on Summary, then click Check for 
Update

Click Download and Update

When asked, enter your passcode

[image: itunes]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with the update to iOS 12 and resolved it by freeing more space on the device, by manually offloading apps or otherwise. I had about 1.5 GB free after download but it only worked after I had about 2 GB free.

Comment: Offloading was only introduced in iOS 11 so the OP can’t do this

Comment: @DaniilManokhin The answer talks about "manually offloading", also known as "deleting" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the error, but I had enough free space, so that was not the problem.

In my case, it was because I had turned off the iPhone pass code. After creating a new pass code, I was able to start the update installation and it went through.